# "Image save as" not allow by jQuery

Tags: jquery, image, drupal

I'm using Drupal 7 and Galleria fullscreen theme.

I protect my images for drag-drop by jQuery.

And now, i want this images not allow right click-save image as by jQuery.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
//disable right click
$('img').bind('contextmenu', function(e){
    return false;
});
```